# Efficient Algorithm for character replacement in a string

Tags: java, algorithm

I have two strings

1. 111TTT0000TT11T00
2. 001101

Now I want to replace all appearances of T in string 1 with character from string 2. Like first T with 0, second T with 0, third T with 1 and so on.

One way of doing so is using while loop and compare every character but in programming sense that's not a good way of acheiving it. Can anybody solve it with better algorithm using JAVA?

```
public void DataParse(String point, String code)
{

    //////////tln("Point:"+point);
    //////////tln("code:"+code);
    //  //////////tln(baseString_temp);

    int counter=0;

    while(baseString_temp.contains(point))
    {      
        if(code!=null)
        {
            String input=String.valueOf(code.charAt(counter));
            //zzzzz(input);


            baseString_temp=baseString_temp.replaceFirst(point,input);
            counter=counter+1;
        }
    }

    ////////////System.out(baseString_temp);
}
```

Comment: "but in programming sense that's not a good way of acheiving it". Why?

Comment: Also, post some code of your attempt first so we can guide you from there.

Comment: As it involves traversing through complete string, reading every character, comparing it and then replace. If some one could better algo for it.

Comment: There is no reason to avoid of loop. You'll need to read every character anyway. There is no method to check and change data but don't read it.

Comment: I wouldn't know how to know a character is a 'T' without reading it. Basically the only way to do it is to traverse through the first string and keep a pointer in the second.
Any calls of high level functions that search for some character are way to expensive. They traverse through the string as well. Hence multiple calls would cause multiple scans.

Comment: Can regular expressions help do it more efficiently? if yes, dont know how to make expression for it.

Comment: @AliJawad in this case you don't need RegExp. Because your have very simple siqusence to find. Actually it's not a sequence at all, just one token. But in case, when seeking sequence is very complex or very mutable - RegExp will be better, indead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every time, when you use `contains` and `replaceFirst`, you force your program enumerate string's character from begining. I believe it will be better to do it in single pass:

```
public static String replaceToken(String primary, String secondary, char token) {

   char [] charArray =primary.toCharArray();

   int counter = 0;
   for(int i=0; i<charArray.length; i++){
       if(charArray[i]==token){
           charArray[i] = secondary.charAt(counter);
           counter++;
           if(counter>=secondary.length()) break;
       }
   }
   return new String(charArray);
}    


public static void main(String[] args) {       
   String result = replaceToken("111TTT0000TT11T00", "001101", 'T');
}
```

---

If you realy would like to use RegExp *so much*, then here you are:

```
public static String replaceSequence(String primary, String secondary, String sequence){

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(sequence + "+");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(primary);

    int counter = 0;
    char [] charArray = primary.toCharArray();

    while(matcher.find() && counter<secondary.length()){
        for(int i = matcher.start(); i<matcher.end(); i++){
            charArray[i] = secondary.charAt(counter++);
            if(counter>=secondary.length()) break;
        }
    }
    return new String(charArray);
}
```

But, based on description of your task, I prefer first approach.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of things. Because Strings are immutable,

```
baseString_temp=baseString_temp.replaceFirst(point,input);
```

will always create a new `String` object (Also, it goes through the string from the beginning, looking for `point`). If you use a `StringBuilder`, you only allocate memory once, and then you can mutate it. Actually, using an array like in Ken's answer would be even better, as it allocates less and has less overhead from method calls.

Also, I'd imagine `contains()` uses a loop of its own, and in the worst case goes to the end of the string. You only need to iterate over the string once, and replace as you go along.

Working example:

```
public class Test {

  private static String replace(char what, String input, String repls) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input);
    int replIdx = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
      if (input.charAt(i) == what) {
        sb.setCharAt(i, repls.charAt(replIdx++));
      }
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(replace('T', "111TTT0000TT11T00", "001101"));
  }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to say in my answer that `replaceFirst` creates new string every time. This will lead to memory spending. That's important note.